# Request to API based on URL/

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm attempting to make a request to an API to get a users' avatar. This is the code I have, however it's returning a "player is not defined" error.

```js
app.get(`/api/avatar/${player}`, function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(`http://cdn.simulping.com/v1/users/${player}/avatar`);
});
```

Essentially, if the URL is `/api/avatar/3925` it would send them to `http://cdn.simulping.com/v1/users/3925/avatar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Express routing, then you would need to utilise route parameters.

The Express documentation provides:

*Route parameters are named URL segments that are used to capture the values specified at their position in the URL. The captured values are populated in the req.params object, with the name of the route parameter specified in the path as their respective keys.*

In this case:

```
Route path: /api/avatar/:player  
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/avatar/3925  
req.params: { "player": "3925" }
```

The working code:

```
app.get('/api/avatar/:player', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(`http://cdn.simulping.com/v1/users/${req.params.player}/avatar`);
});
```

You can read more about it in the Route Parameters section of the [Express Routing Guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Express.JS for the routing, the correct way for doing that is:

```
app.get('/api/avatar/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(`http://cdn.simulping.com/v1/users/${req.params.id}/avatar`);
})
```